# How to cluster objects by shape of their profiles only?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-transformation, distance

This may sound weird, but is it possible to cluster linearly dependent samples (not linearly dependent features)? Suppose I have a matrix, where each row represents a feature vector for a sample:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    1     & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    1     & 3 & 1 & 2 & 9\\
    4       & 4 & 4 & 4&4 \\
9 &9&9&9&8 \\
3 & 4 &1 &2 & 7 \\
7 &6&7&7&8
\end{bmatrix}$

Is there any cluster method, special distance function, or data transformation technique that I can use so that samples 1,3,4,6 (having almost linearly identical profiles) will be in one cluster and sample 2 in one cluster, and sample 5 in another cluster? Euclidean distance won't work in this case because sample 1 and 2 are closer than sample 1 and 4 by this metric and would give wrong results. I want to make the distance between linearly dependent samples small so that I can cluster them (probably through some transformation). Ideally, this linearly dependence can also tolerate some noise, such as sample 4 and 6, which are not exactly the multiples of sample 1.

Comment: If you put the feature vectors as columns, then row reduce, you start at the left of the matrix and make a new cluster whenever you come across a pivot column.  (The columns after a pivot column belong to the cluster associated with that pivot column.)

Comment: Select an appropriate distance function which is sensitive only to _shape_ differences in profiles, not to level differences. Correlation or Penrose shape distance are among those measures.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

First of all, you are looking for something like [Cosine Similarity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). But the question might be seen much deeper. For instance a new metric based on the prependicular distance from equity line (which is $y=x$ in $2D$) would be also interesting. And more deeper, how would you algebraically justify your solution.

I would also recommend to have look at [this](https://scholar.google.de/citations?user=0Hg-Yl4AAAAJ&hl=en) paper which considers convex hull of the data for clustering.